# Why the local time is one hour ahead

Tags: c#, .net, datetime, timezone

I have this string:str1 = "2008-06-01T12:59:59-06:00", when I use `DateTime.Parse(str1)`, it gives me the DateTime instance which has the same year, month and day but the hour becomes 13, minutes is 59 and seconds is 59 with Kind is Local, like the screen shot below.

[image]

I wonder why the hour is 13, is this because the running computer's time zone is US Central Time Zone and Jun 1 is in the Day Light Saving period. However when I used the string "2008-06-01T12:59:59-05:00", the produced DateTime instance has  the hour as 12.

I think -05:00 timezone actually is corresponding to 3 regions which is: (1)Bogoto, Lima (2)Estern Time(US&Canada) (3)Indiana. If the parsing is taking "Day Light Saving" into account, which region it would use, region (1) may not have "Day Light Saving" and (2) have, finally what kind of instance it will produce?

Comment: you want to use DateTimeOffset.Parse instead of dateTime.Parse here

Comment: This string is in the ISO-8601 format.  It deals with daylight savings time by changing the UTC offset.  So it is *actually* a time from the Mountain Standard Time zone.   You get the hour offset because you are in Central.

Comment: This has nothing to do with mountain time. Central Time zone is -6 in standard time and -5 in daylight time.  The date is Jun 1 which should be daylight time (-5) but somebody created this date with standard time (-6).  It really doesn't make a different if the date was produced with -5 or -6 as long as it represents the true time when the data was captured.

Answer (score 1):

Actually, that "2008-06-01T12:59:59-06:00" is always interpreted as '2008-06-01T18:59:59Z' UTC time, than it depends on the running machine's TimeZoneInfo.Local, Date.Parse(str1) convert that UTC time to Central Daylight Saving Time or other time zone's time